# Mongoose discriminator is ignoring an extra field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

So, I have a `Category` model with three discriminators on it. One of them, "Allowance" has a new Schema for an extra field. However, when a new Category is saved to the DB, that field will not save, it is being thrown out by Mongoose.

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "MUST HAVE A NAME"],
        validate: {
            validator: isSanitary,
            message: "NAME CONTAINS ILLEGAL CHARACTERS"
        }
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "MUST CONTAIN AN AMOUNT"]
    },
    removed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}, {discriminatorKey: "kind"});
const Category = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);

Category.discriminator("Income", new mongoose.Schema());

Category.discriminator("Bill", new mongoose.Schema());

Category.discriminator("Allowance",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        isPercent: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    })
);

module.exports = {
    Income: Income,
    Bill: Bill,
    Allowance: Allowance,
    CategorySchema: CategorySchema
};
```

Requiring the model:

```
const {Income, Bill, Allowance} = require("../models/category.js");
```

Code for creating a new Category:

```
/*
    POST: create a new Category
    req.body = {
        account: String (Account id)
        name: String
        amount: Number
        kind: String (Income, Bill, Allowance)
        isPercent: Boolean
    }
    response: Category
    */
    createCategory: function(req, res){
        let category = {
            name: req.body.name,
            amount: req.body.amount,
            removed: false
        };

        switch(req.body.kind){
            case "Income":
                category = new Income(category);
                break;
            case "Bill":
                category = new Bill(category);
                break;
            case "Allowance":
                category = new Allowance(category);
                category.isPercent = req.body.isPercent;
                break;
        }

        res.locals.user.accounts.id(req.body.account).categories.push(category);

        res.locals.user.save()
            .then((user)=>{
                return res.json(category);
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.error(err);
                return res.json("ERROR: unable to create new category");
            });
    },
```

When a new "Allowance" is saved, it saves fine, except that `isPercent` is not saved to the DB. This was working previously but then stopped when I made a tiny change. The only change is that I started exporting the Schema as well as the model. I have no idea how to even debug this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried passing descriminatorKey to each and every schema?

Comment: Just tried it. No difference.

Comment: Can you show how you require the model and how you are creating an Allowance? How exactly are you accessing discriminator model Allowance?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I edited my question it has the require and the function for creating a Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are treating `Category` model the same as the `Allowance` category discriminator model. You cannot save `isPercent` to `Category`, only `Allowance`. Notice in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) that when they want to create a discriminator model, they don't use the base, they use the discriminator. Try instead exporting the discriminator models as well:

```
const Income = Category.discriminator("Income", new mongoose.Schema());
const Bill = Category.discriminator("Bill", new mongoose.Schema());
const Allowance = Category.discriminator("Allowance",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        isPercent: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    })
);

module.exports = {
    CategorySchema,
    Category,
    Income,
    Bill,
    Allowance,
};
```

Then you can update the logic in your route handler to create an `Allowance` or `Category` conditionally:

```
const { Allowance, Category } = require("../models/category");
 
// ...    

// Get correct model based on req.body data
const Model = req.body.kind === "Allowance" ? Allowance : Category;
let category = new Model({
  name: req.body.name,
  amount: req.body.amount,
  kind: req.body.kind,
  isPercent: req.body.kind === "Allowance" ? req.body.isPercent : undefined,
});
```

Hopefully that helps!